# Getting Invalid Identifier for Snowflake Sequence Nextval when running in snowflake environment

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I created a Sequence SEQ_AUTHOR_ID in Snowflake. when I am running the query "select SEQ_AUTHOR_ID.nextval" in the snowflake environment,I had created it in the environment "LIBRARY_CARD_CATALOG.Public" and running the query in same environment. CODE:"SELECT SEQ_AUTHOR_ID.nextval;" I am getting the below Error: invalid identifier 'SEQ_AUTHOR_ID.NEXTVAL'

I want to resolve the Error I tried to run in same Environment but it is not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you have selected the same database in your window. Or try to run with absolute database and Schema name along with the sequence. I tried all the options and it works in my case.

```
SELECT LIBRARY_CARD_CATALOG.Public.SEQ_AUTHOR_ID.NEXTVAL
```